# error 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, unit-of-work

I am using generic repository and unit of work in asp.net MVC. when I want to access the context in controller I get this error:
'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'

however when I comment this line: 
'Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion());'
in Global.asax the error will fix. but as soon as i uncomment that line the error still happening.

here is generic repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal ZarinParse_Context context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ZarinParse_Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWithRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return dbSet.SqlQuery(query, parameters).ToList();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

and unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private ZarinParse_Context context;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        context = new ZarinParse_Context();
    }

    public RoleRepository RoleRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.roleRepository == null)
            {
                this.roleRepository = new RoleRepository(context);
            }
            return roleRepository;
        }
    }

    public UserRepository UserRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.userRepository == null)
            {
                this.userRepository = new UserRepository(context);
            }
            return userRepository;
        }
    }

    public UserRoleRepository UserRoleRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.userRoleRepository == null)
            {
                this.userRoleRepository = new UserRoleRepository(context);
            }
            return userRoleRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

RoleRepository Class:

```
public class RoleRepository : GenericRepository<Role>
{
    public RoleRepository(ZarinParse_Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

my Context:

```
public class ZarinParse_Context : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<TagProduct> TagProducts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserRoleConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TagConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TagProductConfig());
    }
}
```

my Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Role() { Name = "User" };
        unitOfWork.RoleRepository.Insert(model);
        unitOfWork.Save();

        return View();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        unitOfWork.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

and Global.asax File:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ZarinParse_Context, Configuration>());
    }
}
```

and Configuration :

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ZarinParse_Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        ContextKey = "ZarinParse.DomainClasses.Context.ZarinParse_Context";
    }

    protected override void Seed(ZarinParse_Context context)
    {
        InitializeAdmin(context: context,
                        roleName: "Admin",
                        userName: "soheil91141121@gmail.com",
                        password: "stb_91141121",
                        fullName: "سهیل تقی زاده بنگر",
                        mobileNumber: "09356336121",
                        newsEamilEnabled: true);
    }

    private void InitializeAdmin(ZarinParse_Context context, string roleName, string userName, string password, string fullName, bool newsEamilEnabled, string mobileNumber)
    {
        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var roleExist = context.Roles.Any(p => p.Name == roleName);
        if (!roleExist)
        {
            var role = Role.Create();
            role.Name = roleName;

            context.Roles.Add(role);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Create User if it does not exist
        var userExist = context.Users.Any(p => p.UserName == userName);
        if (!userExist)
        {
            var user = User.Create();
            user.UserName = userName;
            user.Email = userName;
            user.Password = password.Encrypt();
            user.FullName = fullName;
            user.NewsEmailEnabled = newsEamilEnabled;
            user.MobileNumber = mobileNumber;

            context.Users.Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Create UserRole if it does not exist
        var role2 = context.Roles.Single(p => p.Name == roleName);
        var user2 = context.Users.Single(p => p.UserName == userName);
        var userRoleExist = context.UserRoles.Any(p => p.RoleId == role2.RoleId && p.UserId == user2.UserId);
        if (!userRoleExist)
        {
            var userRole = UserRole.Create();
            userRole.Role = role2;
            userRole.User = user2;

            context.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You dispose your context in the last line of InitializeAdmin even though it is getting passed in to the method.  If you don't own the creation of an object you shouldn't be disposing of it.

Comment: @Fran thanks . it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of InitializeAdmin disposes a context that is passed into the method.

Only dispose of objects that you have created, since you own the object's lifetime.

In other words, don't dispose of objects you don't own.